# If $f_n \to f$ uniformly and absolutely but $f_n'$ does not exist, can $f'$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

If $f_n$ are continuous and $f_n \to f$ uniformly  but $f_n'$ does not exist, can $f'$ exist? Here I wish to include functions on $\mathbb{C}$ (if it matters)

Comment: What are you assuming about the $f_n$ and $f$? Are they continuous?

Comment: @EthanDlugie Yeah can assume $f_n$ are continuous, so $f$ would be too.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ be the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) which is continuous and bounded. You can pass from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by taking absolute value. The sequence $f/n$ converges uniformly to $0$ because $f$ is bounded, so its uniform limit is everywhere differentiable, but none of the $f/n$ are differentiable.